# Can Consumer and Producer for rabbitmq be deployed as a single web application on tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, rabbitmq

I am using java as back end and wants to integrate rabbitmq for scalability.

My aim here is that .

I have (web application 1)server 1 which will push some message in rabbitmq(i.e act as a producer).

Then i will have some other application 2 deployed on same tomcat  that will consume the messages and

In some cases the consumer itself will have to produce messages to another queue and server 1
 again will consume those messages from another queue(server 1 acting as a consumer).

So here **Server 1** is acting both as a consumer and a producer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer; yes. The longer answer; still yes.

You might not get to reach its full potential, but if your throughput is not that demanding, then you can use this setup.

Comment: Can you provide some example as to how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean? Check out this Hello World example; http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html